# MATLAB - Count if for loop conditions are true

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, timer, count

I have this problem about counting how many times the condition is true in for loop while using a timer object. so I set my timer object calling this function every 60 secs and it will check my condition in the database if X and Z are equal to 1, then it will do something. The problem is that I want it to count every time X and Z are both equal to 1 because I have another program changing values of X and Z every sec. If the count is equal to 1, 2, and 3 it will do differently. When I run it, it doesnt go more than 1 even though X and Z are equal to 1 for many times. Below are my code

```
a = timer('ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate','TimerFcn', 'func(1)', 'Period', 60);
start(a);


function [x] = func(y)
count = 0;
if x == y && z == y
count = count +1;
if count == 1
    disp('1')
elseif count == 2
    disp('2')
elseif count == 3
    disp('3')  
end
else
disp('same')
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is the `count` variable has function-local scope, so it's created every time the function is called and destroyed when the function ends. You need it to persist between calls the the function. One possibility is to make the `count` variable a global:

```
global count;
count = 0;

a = timer('ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate','TimerFcn', 'func(1)', 'Period', 60);
start(a);

function func(y)
global count;
if x == y && z == y
    count = count + 1;
    disp(num2str(count));
else
    disp('same');
end
```

This code also replaces the `if` structure that made the various `disp` calls with a single call to `disp`. If your intention is to print out the count, this is a better method.

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing the first if statement with an end.  Therefore, if count == 1 and everything that follows is only executed when x== y && z == y

Close your first if statement and your code should work:

```
if x == y && z == y
  count = count +1;
end
if count == 1
...
```

Note also that as you have written your code, you have count reset to 0 every time you enter the function, which means that count=count+1; will always be count = 0 + 1 = 1;

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yes, count = count + 1 always equal to 1 every time timer call back this function. I am not sure how to set it in order to next time timer call back AND condition is true, count = 2

Comment: The answer is simple: do not reset it to 0 in the function itself.  Set it in the caller function and pass it as a parameter to func and retrieved it from func every time (i.e. function [x,count] = func(y,count)) or make count a global.  But with either approaches, do NOT set count to zero in the function itself otherwise you will endup resetting that counter every single time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count how many times you get into a function, you must make the counter variable persistent, otherwise it will be set to zero in every call.